# Python module in C for function that doesn't return anything

Tags: python, c, module

I've been working on converting some C code into a Python module. I'm following this tutorial,

http://dan.iel.fm/posts/python-c-extensions/

It's pretty straightforward to make Python module for easy functions like a function for norm like I did in this post,

[Argument passing in Python module written in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661141/argument-passing-in-python-module-written-in-c)

However, I'm confused about what to do with functions where I'm passing pointers and not returning anything.

For example, I have this function in C,

```
void insert_source(node_t *node, source_t *source) {
    node_t *quadrant;
    // Check if the MAX has been reached
    if (node->contents.length == MAX)
        subdivide(node);

    // A node in the tree will be filled with either content or sub
    // quadrants. Check to see whether subquads exist.
    if (node->q1 != NULL) {

        if (source->alpha >= node->xmid) {
            if (source->delta >= node->ymid)
                quadrant = node->q1;
            else
                quadrant = node->q4;
        } else {
            if (source->delta >= node->ymid)
                quadrant = node->q2;
            else
                quadrant = node->q3;
        }
        insert_source(quadrant, source);

    } else {
        // If no subquads exist add source to the list in contents element 
        // Use push() to prepend the source on the list.
        push(&node->contents, source);
    }
}
```

And then my (incomplete) attempt at the wrapper,

```
static void *Quadtree_insert_source(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    PyObject *node_obj, *source_obj;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &node_obj, &source_obj))
        return NULL;

    PyObject *node_array = PyArray_FROM_OTF(node_obj, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_IN_ARRAY);
    PyObject *source_array = PyArray_FROM_OTF(source_obj, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_IN_ARRAY);

    if (node_array == NULL || source_array == NULL) {
        Py_XDECREF(node_array);
        Py_XDECREF(source_array);
    }

    node_t *node = (node_t*)PyArray_DATA(node_array)
    source_t *source = (source_t*)PyArray_DATA(source_array)

    /* Don't know what to put on this line */
    void insert_source(node, source);

    Py_DECREF(node_array);
    Py_DECREF(source_array);

    /* Don't know what to return/if I should return anything */
}
```

The tutorial I linked to said that any function I want to call has to return a PyObject, I just don't know what that's supposed to be in this case.

For reference, here are the structs I'm using in insert_source:

**node_t**

```
typedef struct node_t {
    box_t box;
    double xmid, ymid;
    struct node_t *q1, *q2, *q3, *q4;
    list_t contents;
} node_t;
```

**source_t**

```
typedef struct source_t {
    list_links_t links;
    struct source_t *next, *prev;
    int number;
    double flux_iso, fluxerr_iso, flux_aper, fluxerr_aper;
    double x_image, y_image, alpha, delta;
    double mag_auto, magerr_auto, mag_best, magerr_best;
    double mag_aper, magerr_aper, a_world, erra_world;
    double b_world, errb_world, theta;
    double errtheta, isoarea_img, mu_max, flux_radius;
    int flags;
    double fwhm, elongation, vignet;
    struct source_t *match2, *match3;
} source_t;
```

And Quadtree is just a collection of functions that make up the functionality for a quadtree, including insert_source. The C code is all functional now it's just a matter of making the Python interface.

Answer (score 0):

I read through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)more carefully and saw this

> If you have a C function that returns no useful argument (a function returning void), the corresponding Python function must return None. You need this idiom to do so (which is implemented by the Py_RETURN_NONE macro):
>
> Py_INCREF(Py_None);
>
> return Py_None;

So then would the last part of the wrapper look like this,

```
 insert_source(node, source);

 Py_DECREF(node_array);
 Py_DECREF(source_array);

 Py_INCREF(Py_None);
 return Py_None;
```

? Can anyone confirm?